# I want to change the text size of menu item of my action bar. I have read several posts and tried all but am not getting what i want

Tags: android

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/CustomTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="CustomTitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>
```

I have also tried ActionBar.Menu instead of ActionBar.Title. AppBaseTheme is my app's theme.

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_helpdesk"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="help"
            >
             </item>  
    </menu>
```

And my activity code is :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: post your activity code where you define action bar items

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_helpdesk"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="help"
        >
         </item>

</menu>

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using `android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall`

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">50dp</item>
</style>
```

<

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar">
<item      name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Viadeo.Styled.YourTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
<item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

this is yours `<style name="CustomTitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">`

Just check the value inside parent ie try replacing with this `parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView"`

Comment: check the value in parent that you have given inside TitleTextStyle

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, there was a problem in my code. One style was extending my app theme and making changes to that. That's why it was not working.